# Google NBPhoneNumberUtil is coming up inValid

Tags: ios, swift, libphonenumber

I'm trying to test these valid phone numbers from `Belgium +32 469 12 59 50` and `Malaysia +60 1172249141` but they keep coming up invalid. What could be the issue?

```
let phoneNumber = // either the Belgium number or the Malaysian number with no spaces between numbers
let countryCode = // either BE or MY

let phoneUtil = NBPhoneNumberUtil()
    
do {

    let parsedPhoneNumber: NBPhoneNumber = try phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber, defaultRegion: countryCode)

    var isValid: Bool = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(forRegion: parsedPhoneNumber, regionCode: countryCode)
        
    if !isValid {
        isValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(parsedPhoneNumber) && phoneUtil.isPossibleNumber(parsedPhoneNumber)
    }
        
    return isValid
        
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    return false
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing of whitespaces in phone number before parsing by NBPhoneNumberUtil?

Comment: Hi, I don't use white spaces. I updated the question to reflect it in the comment `// either the Belgium number or the Malaysian number with no spaces between numbers`